# Como analisar sintaticamente HTML malformada?

Tags: php, html, dom, sintaxe, parser

Como parte de um procedimento, preciso extrair o conteúdo de uma tabela presente em uma página. Estou usando cURL para obter os dados brutos em HTML e o [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) para analisar e processar o HTML.

```
<?php

// (...)
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
// (...)
$objPagina = str_get_html($strPagina);
$objItems =  $objPagina->find('table', 0);
echo $objItems->outertext;

?>
```

A princípio tudo funciona conforme desejado. Porém, em um caso específico o HTML recebido está mal-formado. Nesse momento o Simple HTML DOM Parser não consegue processar corretamente o HTML e retorna um resultado incorreto.

O navegador consegue exibir corretamente o conteúdo, mas até onde eu sei os navegadores são projetados para renderizar corretamente um HTML malformado. De fato, se eu abrir  as "ferramentas de desenvolvedor" do Firefox, copiar o HTML exibido ali, colar como um arquivo de texto e usar este texto como fonte para o parser, eu consigo obter o resultado desejado.

Já que não posso modificar o HTML que recebo, o que posso fazer para processar programaticamente o HTML? Me parece que [não devo usar expressões regulares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/798677).

Comment: +1 pela resposta mais épica da história do Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Épica e enganadora. Porque não é correto dizer que nunca se deve usar regex para parsear um trecho qualquer de HTML... Por sinal, o novo design do site ou minha versão do Chrome está enquadrando o Zalgo Text, não aparecem mais os caracteres subindo e descendo.

Comment: @bfavaretto nunca consegui interpretar um html completamente usando expressões regulares – na minha opinião pelos mesmos motivos que a resposta que eu citei dá. Acredito que alguns elementos menos complexos podem sim ser lidos, mas não um documento HTML inteiro.

Comment: Sim Rodrigo, um documento inteiro não dá mesmo. Mas é que aquela resposta chamou tanta atenção que no SO qualquer pergunta sobre extrair alguma coisa de HTML (por exemplo, um atributo de uma única tag numa string de 20 caracteres) acaba marcada como duplicata daquilo.

Comment: Uma opção é usar um *headless browser* para interpretar o documento e gerar uma versão bem formada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode experimentar a extensão [tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) do php.
Com esta extensão é possivel validar e purificar um HTML mal-formado.

Um exemplo (tirado do [manual do php](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php))

```
// Configuração
$config = array(
           'indent'         => true,
           'output-xhtml'   => true,
           'wrap'           => 200);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

// Output
echo $tidy;
```

Apenas observar que no site oficial da extensão parece que a última atualização ocorreu em 2009, portanto pode ser que esta solução não resolva seu problema.

Comment: "Newest official release 5.6.0, November 2017. If you want the latest official, get the master branch of our tidy-html5 repository" http://www.html-tidy.org/ ou https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta usar o `xmllint` diretamente.

1) instalar o xmllint (ferramente minúiscula e gratuita)

> preciso extrair o conteúdo de uma tabela presente

2) Invoca

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//table' 'http://my.remote.page/x.html' > tabelas.txt
```

(adapta a expressão xpath às tuas necessidades) e
se der resultados, insere a invocação no Php